# Generate Bootstrap Modal in Asp.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

Currently i have button, when click on it new window is opened with some generated data :

```
function SynopsisWindowOpen(obj) {
    var title = $(obj).find("strong[name='title']").html();
    var url = "/ratings/Synopsis.aspx?logoonly=1&Certificate=" + obj.id + "&Title=" + encodeURIComponent(title);

    window.open(url, 'synopsis', 'location=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,copyhistory=yes,width=600,height=500,left=10, top=10,screenX=10,screenY=10');
}
```

But i want to make from this browser window - modal window.

So i add instead of

```
window.open(url, 'synopsis', 'location=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,copyhistory=yes,width=600,height=500,left=10, top=10,screenX=10,screenY=10');
```

code

```
$("#RatingModal").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
    $(this).find(".modal-content").load(url);
    });
    $("#RatingModal").modal('show');
```

Also change view `/ratings/Synopsis.aspx` to fit my modal window.

Problem : when window is opened all scripts, css files etc. that were included on Master page re-added again, as `/ratings/Synopsis.aspx` are inherited from Master Page.

I don't know how to make Partial View in Web Forms if i can compare it with MVC

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you do not add a second master page that does not include styles and scripts and associate Synopsis.aspx with this additional master page?

Comment: @schudel, i red about this, but i hope there is another solution without adding new Master page